# Importing google user profile to remote db on android

Tags: android, google-api-java-client, android-networking

I'm building an app on android that has the features of Log-in with `facebook` and Log-in with `Google`. Assuming the user chooses to login with google, I would like to ask for permission and collect basic information such as name,age,sex,location,email from his profile and save it on my server's database.

Here is the problem: Which api should I actually use to grab these info? I don't think google+ api would be a proper choice since not every google user has one. After checking [Google-api-java-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) documentation, I still cant find anything useful.
There seem to be no library for this basic operation.

The only thing that seems relevant is [Google Apps Profile API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/profiles/) but
 1. it's outdated.
 2. Its not free.

I'm too confused and I hope someone can guide me through this nightmare.

**Edit**: found some new relevant info but I'm still hoping to find an official java library for this:
https://oauthssodemo.appspot.com/step/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what I was looking for: http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg-history/c35433d3077dc4eb89dccb25618dc70dbd375d65/apis/oauth2/v2/com/google/api/services/oauth2/model/Userinfo.html